# CordovaApp - AngularJs - app.initialize() -> undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I've an hybrid for android, made with cordova + onsen + angularJs.

This is the index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>AppModel</title>  

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins.css"/> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/plugins.less"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css">  

    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/app.less"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/base-layout.less"/>

</head>

<body>    

<ons-sliding-menu
    menu-page="modules/core/menu.html" main-page="modules/account_profile/login.html" side="left"
    var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="true" swipe-target-width="50">
</ons-sliding-menu>


<script src="css/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>   
<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular-touch.js"></script>    
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>  

  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>         
  <script src="js/lodash_3.2.0.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="js/angular-google-maps_2.0.12.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>   

<script src="js/appStart.js"></script>      
<script src="js/data/data.js"></script>    
<script src="js/angularApp/controllers.js"></script>      
<script src="js/angularApp/directives.js"></script>      
<script src="js/angularApp/filters.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

  <script>
    app.initialize();
   </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

And this is the appStart.js file:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'

exitFunction : function(){
     if (navigator.notification.confirm("Vuoi chiudere l'app?", 
            function(index) {
                if (index == 1) { // OK button
                    navigator.app.exitApp(); // Close the app
                }
            },
            "AppModel",
            ["Ok","Annulla"]
        ));
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    ons.setDefaultDeviceBackButtonListener(function() {
        if (navigator.notification.confirm("Vuoi chiudere l'app?", 
            function(index) {
                if (index == 1) { // OK button
                    navigator.app.exitApp(); // Close the app
                }
            },
            "AppModel",
            ["Ok","Annulla"]
        ));
    });

    /*
    // Open any external link with InAppBrowser Plugin
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href^=http], a[href^=https]', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this); 
        var target = $this.data('inAppBrowser') || '_blank';

        window.open($this.attr('href'), target);

    });
    */

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this); 
        //var target = $this.data('inAppBrowser') || '_blank';

        window.open($this.attr('href'), "_system");

    });


},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    //var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    //var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    //var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    //listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    //receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}

};


(function() {

var app = angular.module('AppModel', ['onsen', 'angular-carousel', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'])    
.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|ftp|mailto|tel|geo):/);            
    }
]);


document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['AppModel']);       
}, false);    


})();
```

But the chrome inspect console says, undefined is not a function, referred to the script in index.html

```
   <script>app.initialize();</script>
```

What's the problem?
Thank you

Comment: You need to add ng-app in HTML page

Comment: Also adding ng-app, nothing changed. The angular bootstraping was here:

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['AppModel']);       
}, false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution by myself:

i created a new file and called index.js, here is the content

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'

exitFunction : function(){
     if (navigator.notification.confirm("Vuoi chiudere l'app?", 
            function(index) {
                if (index == 1) { // OK button
                    navigator.app.exitApp(); // Close the app
                }
            },
            "AppModel",
            ["Ok","Annulla"]
        ));
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    ons.setDefaultDeviceBackButtonListener(function() {
        if (navigator.notification.confirm("Vuoi chiudere l'app?", 
            function(index) {
                if (index == 1) { // OK button
                    navigator.app.exitApp(); // Close the app
                }
            },
            "AppModel",
            ["Ok","Annulla"]
        ));
    });

    /*
    // Open any external link with InAppBrowser Plugin
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href^=http], a[href^=https]', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this); 
        var target = $this.data('inAppBrowser') || '_blank';

        window.open($this.attr('href'), target);

    });
    */

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this); 
        //var target = $this.data('inAppBrowser') || '_blank';

        window.open($this.attr('href'), "_system");

    });


},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    //var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    //var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    //var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    //listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    //receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}

 };


  app.initialize(); //moved here this instruction
```

and then in the index.html body, as the last imported script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

And everything works.